# Should I use prototype or not?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Vector class, which can basically hold three numerical values. However, a lot of operations can be done on such a vector - e.g. getting the magnitude, adding or subtracting another vector etc.

I was wondering whether these functions should be coded as being a prototype function of the Vector class, or that I should define them in the constructor.

So which of these two methods is preferable?

```
function Vector3D(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y
    this.z = z;
}

Vector3D.prototype.magnitude = function() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z);
};
```

or

```
function Vector3D(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;

    this.magnitude = function() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is exactly the situation for using prototype. I see two main benefits for doing so:

1. **Functions are not created multiple times**. If you define the functions inside the constructor, a new anonymous function is being created for each function you define, *every time the constructor is called*. Prototypes are static objects, and each instance of Vector3D will simply *reference* the prototype functions.
2. **The prototype is a single object that can be easily manipulated**. This affords great flexibility; unfortunately I'm only able to provide a few examples of what this can offer:

   1. If you wanted to create a child class, for example Vector3DSpecial, you can simply clone `Vector3D.prototype` and assign this to `Vector3DSpecial.prototype`. While you can also do this using constructors by `Vector3DSpecial.prototype = new Vector3D();`, constructors may contain side-effects which will get executed in that simple prototype assignment, and therefore should be avoided. With prototypes, you may even choose only particular functions in the prototype to be copied over to the new class.
   2. Adding methods to `Vector3D` is simply a matter of adding properties to the prototype, and allows your code to be more easily split / organised into multiple files, or to allow for adding methods in other parts of the code dynamically. Sure, you can do a combination of adding methods in the constructor and via the prototype, but that is inconsistent and is likely to lead to more complexity further down the track.

When would I **not** use prototype? For singleton objects, for example a controller that interacts with a page and may delegate work off to other objects. A global "notification" object is one such example. Here, extending is unlikely, and the object is only created once, making the prototype an additional (conceptual) complexity.

Answer (score 9):

Prototyped methods would only work for public properties, if you would keep track of x, y, z as "private" variables the prototype would not work.

I would use the latter, because you might want methods that only work with private/internal variables, but it all depends on context.

```
function Vector3D(x, y, z) {
   // x, y, z is automatically in this scope now, but as private members.
   this.magnitude = function() {
        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z *z);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. x, y and z should also be able to be extracted from an instance of Vector3D, so they ought to be public. In this case, would prototype be the best choice?

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but I prefer prototypes, since anything private in js is a pipedream, and will usually only make it harder for you to unit test your code - who are you hiding the stuff from except yourself :)

Comment: I agree with you, hence I only have public variables only. In Google Chrome's Developer Tools functions are shown as members too if passed though the constructor, while it would be more practical if they would be 'hidden' in the prototype and that only x, y and z would show up there.

Comment: Well, "hiding it for yourself" is true in most cases, but there are plenty of js-frameworks that would benefit from hiding internal structure to prevent misuse of the code. I get your point though.

Comment: @jishi Currently the convention would be to use `_someprivate` JavaScript does not support private but it does support prototype very well. So you're hacking something that's not supported by the language to throw away something that is supported by the language. With supported I mean that JS engines will optimise your code for it.

Answer (score -2):

ECMA 6 http://es6-features.org/#BaseClassAccess

```
class Shape {
    …
    toString () {
        return `Shape(${this.id})`
    }
}
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    constructor (id, x, y, width, height) {
        super(id, x, y)
        …
    }
    toString () {
        return "Rectangle > " + super.toString()
    }
}
class Circle extends Shape {
    constructor (id, x, y, radius) {
        super(id, x, y)
        …
    }
    toString () {
        return "Circle > " + super.toString()
    }
}
```

ECMA 5

```
var Shape = function (id, x, y) {
    …
};
Shape.prototype.toString = function (x, y) {
    return "Shape(" + this.id + ")"
};
var Rectangle = function (id, x, y, width, height) {
    Shape.call(this, id, x, y);
    …
};
Rectangle.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Rectangle > " + Shape.prototype.toString.call(this);
};
var Circle = function (id, x, y, radius) {
    Shape.call(this, id, x, y);
    …
};
Circle.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Circle > " + Shape.prototype.toString.call(this);
};
```