# Add method direct to constructor vs add method via prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript

We get same result from below given method. But which is more efficient way to do it and which one take less space in memory.

```
function a(){
this.addclass= function(){
//do something
}
}

function a(){}
a.prototype.addclass= function(){
//do something
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use prototype or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691044/should-i-use-prototype-or-not)

Comment: they use about the same amount of ram these days. the 2nd is a hair faster to instantiate while the first one's methods resolve slightly faster. slightly, and rarely enough to matter as much as coding convenience or readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find both of the ways, you suggested, to behave differently considering case of inheritance which is apparent by the following section of codes:

Defining `addclass` method through `prototype`

```
function a() {
   a.prototype.addclass= function() {
      alert('a');
   };
}

a();

function b() {}

b.prototype = Object.create(a);
var o = new b();
o.prototype.addclass();
```

Defining `addclass` method with `this`

```
function a() {
   this.addclass= function(){
      alert('a');
   };
}

a();

function b() {}

b.prototype = Object.create(a);
var o = new b();
o.prototype.addclass();
```

Through prototype (first one) will have access to `addclass` method of its parent, whereas through this (second one), access to `addclass` is specific to instances of 'a' function.